# What do you call one-color concept variations?

Tags: terminology

When reviewing logo concepts submitted from designers, I want to ask them to include a single-color gray version, like something that would be stamped in a background. Is there a name for this in the graphic design world?

Comment: See my answer below: another way would be to ask for a screened-tint of the line copy. Then specify the screen as a %. Start with a 10% which should work. Make 2% adjustments to suit your stationery.

Answer (score 6):

There's a simple word for this:

> monotone

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you're hiring designers that are skilled at presenting their work to you. A skilled designer will take into consideration the project requirements and present designs that accommodate said requirements. MOST (thought not all) logo designs typically will require the use of one-color versions and, at least at the early stages, most logo designs *are* presented in one color versions.

As for terminology, it's 'one color' or, perhaps 'black and white'.

Comment: DA01- "most logo designs are presented in one color versions"- that's what I thought too, but I'm using 99 designs and almost no ones doing it- I just wanted to know how to give them instructions to do so.

Comment: "but I'm using 99 designs" = that's your problem. Those folks aren't professional designers. You rarely get what you pay for on that site (which is little to begin with).

Comment: DA01- Couldn't agree more- first and last time on 99 Designs- mea culpa

Answer (score 3):

Monochrome is the use of one shade or color. Images using only shades of grey are called greyscale, but the use of "black and white" will do the job just as well.

Comment: I believe the term reserved for neutrals is achromatic (having no colour.)

Comment: Yes, in some cases that is correct, in others, there are undertones of color. You will notice that I did not use the terminology "achromatic" or "neutral" because that is not what the question was about. "I want to ask them to include a single-color gray version,"--my use is correct if you look at the definition of monochrome("describes paintings, drawings, design, or photographs in one color or shades of one color."-wiki) and grey("Grey or gray is an intermediate color between black and white,"-wiki).

Comment: Never said you were incorrect. I was merely adding a term and its qualifier. We are a bunch of nit-pickers in search for accuracy and occasionally added detail.

Comment: Fair enough. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

A single color is known as `spot color`.

That's all you need to say. Don't say grey: that is both the name of a color AND and a term for the range of "colors" (256 of them in 8-bit CG).

Comment: Black is usually not considered a spot colour. Black is the printer's favourite colour, in fact. It is part of the normal four standard-colour process colours. Spot colours are "mixed" colours that will add to the cost of the job unnecessarily in the case of black. No, Do that and you'll be spotted for a novice.

Comment: "Black" appears nowhere in my answer. The OP is asking for a spot color. He/she said "grey" in an ambiguous way which *might* refer to providing a greyscale computerized image which would be screened and printed one color. I note that your comment to the OP has more useful information than your actual answer: if the OP wants to print a solid black line drawing in a "faded version of [any] color" then a "X% screen tint of [color]" is certainly a good way to state it.

Comment: Sorry, I reacted to your use of grey in your example. Grey to me is a tint of black. My comments were made at different times. My mind works like that. By the way, A single colour is not known as spot colour. Maybe I should ask where is a single colour known as a spot colour. Please refine your definition.

Comment: Any color which required a special ink and has its own plate is a spot color. CMYK are in fact spot colors in the same way that a square is a rectangle. They are *very specific* spot colors called the "process colors."

Comment: You are incorrect.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_color ; http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/spot_color.html ; http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6cafa.html ; http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/Pantone.aspx?pg=19890

Comment: The first reference you provide is incorrect. The rest appear to agree with me and dispute your statement regarding the process colours. Without pursuing the differences here in a comment, the use of the terms process and spot interchangeably is confusing the essential difference between them. You have chosen a bad metaphor.

Comment: I never used them interchangeably. Process colors are, by definition, spot colors. They are just universally agreed upon for commercial printing and have an implicit screen angle. In any event what I said was "special inks" (e.g. not CMYK) require an extra plate and are called spot colors universally. I am struggling to see how you feel that "a single color not being a spot color" is a proper definition. certainly all the references above dispute your odd definition.

Comment: You are confused. You have misinterpreted the definitions you provided. Seek informed explanation from someone who can take the time to point out your confusion between the two. This is the end of my attempts to define the term, here. There is an additional glossary of graphic design and printing terms at prepressure.com. Please do not take this as any form of disrespect. I can see that you are a highly-respected contributor. I offer the comment with the humblest of apologies for using this as a venue for comment. Please forgive me for not finding a more appropriate place off-site.

Comment: Stan, you haven't made ANY attempt to "define the term." I also note with interest that you failed to define the term in your answer to  a question specifically about what a spot color is and when to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the designer to include "a single-colour grey version like something that would be stamped in the background." Then show a sample if you can find one.

As you can see, even if you know the right term (a grey watermark — a "watermark" is barely visible and not very detailed). Many know it by another name and clear communications is what you should strive to attain. Describe what you want in the most clear terms available. It is an asset to be armed with the right terminology; but, that doesn't mean the contractor is aware of it. We are visual. Be redundant.

So, both sides must be precise in their communication. Visual artists can illustrate unambiguously while words can be vague when trying to describe concept.

Answer (score 1):

The stamp in the background is known as a watermark.

A one color image would be monochrome.

Comment: Just as a semantic question, can a gray-scale image be considered monochrome?

Comment: Ryan- thanks, but as Johannes points out, [monochrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome) means 1 color but can have different shadings. Like gray scale. I'm looking for the black & white equivilant.

Comment: In your question you asked for one color which to me means you don't want to pay a printer to use more then one color which is what monochrome gets you. A gray-scale image is considered monochrome because it would only use black ink. I'm not familiar with any set term otherwise especially if you wanted gray. Your best bet is to say a "one-color logo" or "solid gray logo" although that is weird and easier to just say "solid black logo"

Comment: Ryan- this has nothing to do with printing- most modern logos have a flat one-color representation and just wanted to know if there's a name for it

Comment: Yes, I understand that now but your question didn't specify that to begin with. I was merely explaining why I answered as I did.

Comment: @Johannes Yes. There is only one hue. A value scale of hues is a monochrome. One hue would be a monotone.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry I gave the wrong info in the comment. <blush> A grey scale of black tints, a grey-scale image is acromatic (having no colour) a special case of monochomatic. A one hue plus white plus black (similar to a duo-tone) would be monochromatic (having one colour).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this.

```
a single-color gray version
```

According to me it would be like using a main color such as `blue` and the light shade of the same `blue` will be the gray version of the same, we use the same technique in all other color's also.

If you are familiar with [tint and shades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades) than you can use this term to make designer understand. such as you can say use the `light shade of red` with this `killing(blood) red` show me some more tints and shades of the same color which goes well with this.

And that would be more easy for you and for the designer if you show them any example logo which clearly says your word `look how beautifully logo is stamped in this background` i need such looks and feels in my logo too.

A good read from my point of view, if you have spare time : [Color harmony Logo](http://www.dynamicgraphics.com/dgm/Article/28708/index.html)

Hope this will help a bit..

Comment: Nomenclature Nazi: A tint is a hue containing white. A shade is a hue containing black. A tone is a hue containing white and black. Grey is a tint of black. A "light _shade_ of red" should be re-worded to "light tint of red."

Comment: @Stan, feel free to make edits where you see fit.